# ExactTarget Push Error Log

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have registered Sandbox account in [App-Center](https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/#app-center) and created a new API-Integration Apps and provided all the access included Push.

We are invoking the below REST API to send Push notification with the token. Below are the request and response.

However, the push notification is not sent to the device. Kindly let us know how can we verify in ExactTarget, if the message was sent or if there any error log that can be verified?

**Request**

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/send
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "DeviceTokens": [
        "****************************"
    ]
}
```

**Response**

```
Response Payload:
{"tokenId":"*************************"}
Response status is 202 Accepted.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues, contact support and ask them to review the logs for your account (MID) to see if there is anything in your app logs.